# How to access to an object value (it always prints memory address)

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsobject

I have the following class:

```
@interface TTFacebookPost : NSObject {
  NSDate*   _created;
  NSNumber* _postId;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSDate*   created;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSNumber* postId;


@end
```

And when I try to access the postId in another class it always retrieves a memory address or a number that i do not know where it comes:

```
TTFacebookPost *post = cell.userInfo;
NSLog(@"Post url is: %i", post.postId);
```

and the result is:

```
 Post url is: 118538496
```

this number is not saved anywhere in the object, so I do not know where is coming.

This is how looks the object in memory:

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's an object you use `%@` to get the result of the `-(NSString *)description` method.

That's usually what you want for debugging. But it's usually not what you want to present it to the user. You would use a [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like NSLog(@"Post url is: %@", post.postId);

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Post url is: %f",[post.postId floatValue]);
```

OR

```
NSLog(@"Post url is: %d",[post.postId intValue]);
```

OR

```
NSLog(@"Post url is: %d",[post.postId boolValue]);
```

depending on whether you're using the NSNumber to store a float, int or boolean.